# How to make an image appear then another takes its place and so on?

Tags: images, css, admin, homepage, code

i would like to reproduce the same effect than this website's homepage has (https://studioswine.com/), which consists of an image appearing randomly in the space for a very short time, then disappears and another image appears in a different place, and so on.

Im new to Wordpress and i dont know how to code, but i guess the change must be made in the additionnal CSS editor in the wordpress editor.

Thanks in advance, and pardon my english, this is not my mother tongue.
Have a nice day.

Comment: it's done with javascript, this isn't really a WordPress question though other than the coincidence you want the final result to be on a WP site. What you need is frontend help not WordPress help. Looking at the site, the author has put a lot of `<img>` tags in a div, then set everything in that div to be hidden. They've then manually positioned every single image, and written JS to unhide them one by one on a timer. There is nothing random about the locations, they've been preset/chosen manually. Maybe this would have been more appropriate on stackoverflow?

Comment: Perhaps that would have been more appropriate on stackoverflow, to be honest i dont really know what all of this means, i'm very new to wordpress and programming in general. I'll post my question in the appropriate section, thanks a lot.